# [Symfony3][Doctrine] Problem with the query generated while persisting an entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a surprising problem with my Symfony 3.4 app.
Every time I try to persist an entity in a controller, I get a SQLSTATE[HY093] error, because the query generated only set one parameter.
For exemple, I get this trying to persist a new object "norm" :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO norm(min, max, tech, project_id, type_id, ca_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["18"]:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

So here the query set only one param ("18") which is totaly anormal.

IMPORTANT NOTES : 
The problem is totaly new, while my app is several monthes old. 
The problem applies to the totality of my app.
There was no problems at all before today (but I'm not sure if it started today).
I work in localhost on a Windows 10 PC with wampserver, and all my other local apps/websites have no problem like this one.

[UPDATE]
The issue is gone. Here's the solution for those who have the same (or similar) problem : 
just delete the vendor folder and run `composer update` (make sure to bakcup the folder). That's it.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You're trying to create a record into table `norm` and set 6 columns. You provide 1 column. So, something has changed. Could be your server (updated wamp?), project (ran a `composer update`?), or any number of things. What have you tried to find the issue and what have you tried to solve it?

Comment: To solve it I tried to reset wamp services, clear symfony's cache, run composer update.
But first I tried to add and update other entities in my app, and I did the same in other local apps, it helped me find out the issue was about this app only, but with every entities of the app.
I didn't update wamp recently nor running composer update. I'm trying to figure what I changed...

Comment: `git log`? And/or compare with repo branch versions? (If you're using PhpStorm and have your project in git, got to _Settings > Version Control_ and check "Show directories with changed descendants" for highlighting in the folder explorer.

Comment: I verified and... it apears that I did a "composer update" before my last git commit. Only twig and symfony were updated. I changed the symfony version to go back to the previous one, but the issue is still here...

Comment: Ok so I just delete the vendor folder and run composer update and the issue was gone... I have no idea what I did in this folder to get this issue.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your query need 6 params but you only set 1 param ["18"]
check your code and verify what you sending to the insert query

Comment: Please read my post carefuly, this issue is about my entire app, which have many entities, but the issue apeared suddenly. The issue isn't about my code in the controlers, which only persist entities (and did well since this morning).

Comment: you didnt change anything in your config or code today?

Comment: In the code yes but the issue also apply to controllers I didn't change.
I realized I made a "composer update" a few days ago which updated the symfony version, so I just tried to come back to the previous verison, but this didn't fix the issue.
The only other configuration change was is services.yml, in wich I added an entry for the sonata admin bundle, but I'm 90% sure that was before the issue apears.

Comment: Ok so I just delete the vendor folder and run composer update and the issue was gone... I have no idea what I did in this folder to get this issue.
Thanks for your help

Comment: IIf you dont change anything in your composer.json then use composer install better, use composer update only if you added new packages to update your composer.lock